# Flush caches after renaming Kubernetes provider account

Tags: spinnaker

I renamed the default `my-kubernetes-account` Kubernetes provider credential name by GCP Spinnaker deployment and now I ended up with having both on my spinnaker UI.

I tried to clear my browser's local storage or even remove it from `application -> config -> Application Attributes -> Accounts`, but none of them helped.

Is there any way to re-index providers or remove it in some way?

**Update:**
Would it help to remove all the related keys in `redis`, like:

`redis-cli KEYS "*my-kubernetes-account:*" | xargs redis-cli DEL`

Or is it a tottaly bad idea? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, flushing the redis db is the correct way to remove the duplicate entries.

Any of the cached infrastructure details that you remove from redis will be automatically recreated by the caching agents.

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: I can confirm, `flushall` in redis did the job :)